# displaying of pointcloud crashes rviz

Tags: rviz, pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using pcl and pcl_ros from
http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/tags/unstable/perception_pcl/.
I am publishing the pointcloud version .PCD v.7 using
pcd_to_pointcloud tool and then trying to display it in diamondback
version of rviz.

The latter however crashes rviz with the following message:
"""
rviz: /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.0/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:252:
void Ogre::AxisAlignedBox::setExtents(const Ogre::Vector3&, const
Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `(min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z
<= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal
to maximum corner"' failed.
(0) : fatal error C9999: *** exception during compilation ***
"""

I suspect it to be caused by NaNs in my pointcloud but then again this
was not the problem for diamondback version of pcl_ros.
Can anyone confirm if my guess is right and what would would the
action to rectify the problem be?

D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10110/displaying-of-pointcloud-crashes-rviz/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-17**:
Closing as Eric Perko's comment is essentially the right answer.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-30**:
Could you try it on rviz trunk? If it still doesn't work there, I suggest opening a ticket and then putting a link to it here as the answer. If a valid PointCloud (according to the PointCloud2 message type) causes rviz to crash, it's definitely a bug :)

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2011-05-30**:
Hi Eric, the bt is here: http://pastie.org/1995774. And this is the pcd I am trying to visualize: [http://ias.cs.tum.edu/~pangerci/alpen_milch_0195.pcd](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/%7Epangerci/alpen_milch_0195.pcd). It seems like the deb version of rviz is built w/o debug symbols as I am not able to get any listing of the code or such.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-30**:
Could you run rviz in gdb and get a backtrace?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-05-30**:
This might be the same issue?: http://answers.ros.org/question/928/rviz-window-closes-itself Spoiler alert, no solutions there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you try it on rviz trunk? If it still doesn't work there, I suggest opening a ticket and then putting a link to it here as the answer. If a valid PointCloud (according to the PointCloud2 message type) causes rviz to crash, it's definitely a bug :) - Eric Perko (May 30)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0